# Preparing Grid weather data for ConvLSTM2d

Tags: python, numpy, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am attempting to use a ConvLSTM2d model using hourly grid weather data.  I can get the data into a 4d array with these dimensions (num_hours, lat, lon, num_features).  ConvLSTM2d requires 5d and I was planning on setting a variable for sequence length of maybe 24hrs.  My question is how do i create an additional dimension in this array to have the sequence length dimension?(num_hours, sequence_length, lat, lon, num_features) Is there a smarter, more efficient way to get the data in the correct form from a pandas dataframe that has columns for lat, lon, time, feature type & value?

*
I realize it is always easier to have a sample dataset when asking a question so i created a set to mimic the issue.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

weather_variables = ['windspeed', 'temp','pressure']
lats = [x/10 for x in range(400,500,5)]
lons = [x/10 for x in range(900,1000,5)]
hours = pd.date_range('1/1/2021', '9/28/2021', freq= 'H')

df = []
for i in range (0, len(hours)):
    for weather in weather_variables:
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame(index = lats, columns = lons,data = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(lats), len(lons))))
        temp_df = temp_df.unstack().to_frame()
        temp_df.reset_index(inplace= True)
        temp_df['weather_variable'] = weather 
        temp_df['ts'] = hours[i] 
        df.append(temp_df)

df = pd.concat(df)
df.columns = ['lon','lat','value','weather_variable', 'ts']
```

So this code will create a dummy dataset containing a 3 grids for a given hour.  The goal is to convert this into a 5d array of overlapping 24 hours sequences.  The array would look like this i think (len(hours)?, 24, 20, 20, 3)

Answer (score 0):

From the [ConvLSTM paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2015/file/07563a3fe3bbe7e3ba84431ad9d055af-Paper.pdf),

> The weather radar data is recorded every 6 minutes, so there
> are 240 frames per day. To get disjoint subsets for training, testing and validation, we partition each
> daily sequence into 40 non-overlapping frame blocks and randomly assign 4 blocks for training, 1
> block for testing and 1 block for validation. The data instances are sliced from these blocks using
> a 20-frame-wide sliding window. Thus our radar echo dataset contains 8148 training sequences,
> 2037 testing sequences and 2037 validation sequences and all the sequences are 20 frames long (5
> for the input and 15 for the prediction).

If my calculations are correct, each of the "non-overlapping frame blocks" should have 6 frames in it (240 frames per day / 40 blocks per day = 6 frames per block). So I'm not sure how you create a 20-frame-wide sliding window in a given block. Nonetheless, you could take a similar approach: divide your data into non-overlapping windows of a specific length. Perhaps you use 6 hours of data to predict the next 6. I'm not sure that you need to keep the windows within a given day--a change from 11 pm to 1 am seems just as valid a time window as from say 3 am to 5 am.

I don't think Pandas will be an efficient way to massage the data. I would stick with NumPy or probably a [TensorFlow data structure](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data).